# Weird Question with def, and condition

Tags: macros, conditionals, def

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\ENLANG{english}
\def\FRLANG{french}
\def\LANG{\ENLANG}
\begin{document}
\if\LANG\ENLANG \ENLANG \else \FRLANG \fi

\ifx\LANG\ENLANG \ENLANG \else \FRLANG \fi

\LANG\ \ENLANG\ \FRLANG
\end{document}
```

Really weird to me. It outputs french for both if and ifx. But I expect it to be english and english.

What should I do if I want at least one of if and ifx to give true and output english instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your expectations are wrong, sorry.

When TeX sees `\if\LANG` it expands `\LANG` and gets `\ENLANG`, which is expandable so at the end we get `\if en` which returns false.

On the other hand, `\ifx` returns true, in the case both the following tokens are macros, when the first level expansions are the same; but they arent, because `\LANG` expands to `\ENLANG` and `\ENLANG` expands to `english`.

You can compare with `\ifx`, provided you do

```
\let\LANG=\ENLANG
```

rather than `\def\LANG{\ENLANG}`.

Answer (score 1):

`\if\LANG`

expands `\LANG` until it gets two non expandable tokens `e` and `n` in this case and compares them, so will give false and skip to `\else`.

`\ifx\LANG\ENLANG`

is false as they have different defintions, `\LANG` is defined to have replacement `\ENLANG` and `\ENLANG` is defined to have replacement `english`

---

You can arrange that `\LANG` has a suitable definition for `\ifx` eg

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\ENLANG{english}
\def\FRLANG{french}
\edef\LANG{\ENLANG}
\begin{document}


\ifx\LANG\ENLANG THIS: \ENLANG \else NOT THIS: \FRLANG \fi


\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering! In this case, if I want \if or \ifx to give true what should I do

Comment: @Twilight see update

Comment: Thank you so much! Really appreciated.